# Programmatically managing a 'balance' of time (sick/vacation)

Tags: python, django, database-design, date, time

I'm using Python/Django, but this is more about the "data model" and how I interact with the information - I really just want to know if I'm crazy here.

I'm working on a small app at my company (~55 employees) that will keep track of available Vacation/Sick time. Part of the purpose is to integrate "self-service" into our intranet, so that employees can submit "Time Off Requests" electronically, instead of filling out and handing in paper to HR.

Obviously, this app needs to keep a running balance per employee, and will be validating that the employee has enough Vacation remaining for whatever they're requesting.

Like with financial/accounting software, I know that I shouldn't necessarily be storing float values, or just keeping a single running balance.

My idea is to use a database table structure like the following to store time "credits" and "debits":

`Employee | Year | Credit/Debit | Amount | Timestamp`

'Year' would be the year to which the credit/debit belong, because Vacation and Sick time are handled on a yearly basis, *not* on a running balance per employee.

To determine the employees available Vacation/Sick time, I would get the 'transactions' for the employee for the given year, and find the balance.

I know I'm leaving out lots of information, but I was wondering: **Does this seem like a reasonable way to go about this,** being as that it needs to be very accurate, **or** am I completely over-complicating this?

Comment: ONe thing to consider is internal controls, make sure the tables cannot be accessed by any employees except the dba except through the application and do not use anything except stored procs to avoid having direct table access or the ability to do anything except what is defined by the user interface. Otherwise there will be timecard fraud where people can "adjust" their hours on the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think your solution is complicated, it's not.  Modeling sick/vacation days as accounts that are linked to employees is a very good idea and can be dead easy.

In the simplest case, you can have a "transactions" table, and a "account" table, such that re-running all the transactions from the beginning of the year (for each account) will yield a sum that exactly matches the balance.

> Transactions
>
> ID | Account | Delta | Timestamp
>
> Account
>
> ID | Name | Employee | Year | Balance

The transactions provide an audit trail, and the balance provides a point of reference for your next transaction. By ensuring the two match, you've ensured consistency (though, not necessarily correctness - that's got to be checked with unit tests on each type of transaction, i.e. deposit, withdrawal)

I'd recommend a "Transaction Detail" table that refers to the Transactions.ID, and includes all the nice stuff you want like who initiated it, notes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Just trying to make sure I'm not *Doing It Wrong*. =)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good start. A couple of points:

- The credits would be autogenerated by the system at the begining of the year, and debits would be created by employees. Should there be a field to indicate who/what created the transaction?
- Do you have a mechanism for indicating what *kind* of time off is requested? I don't know what your company is like but some companies treat vacation and sick time differently. Then there's also caregiver time, time off for compassion grounds (such as a relative dies), time off for civic and statutory holidays, time off for religions holidays, time off for.... well you get the idea. Maybe you want different types of time off to be worth different amounts of credit. Some organizations do that. Do you plan to track these different time-off codes as well? Is it something that you should plan for if you think it will be an issue in the future?

Comment: Yes, there will be a field to determine who/what caused a given transaction. I mentioned in another comment that the Requests themselves are another 'model' that get Approved/Denied, and generally only Approval would generate a Debit transaction.

Comment: As for what *kind* of transaction, yes. The only two types of time that actually have to be accounted, in this case, are Vacation and Sick. They are calculated very differently, but it's likely that 'Sick' would get its own Ledger. In any case, I just want to make sure that I'm storing these 'account transactions' in a sane manner. Thank you very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I also agree it's a good start.

I don't see any fields for approval / disapproval.  If this app is meant to be used also by HR, then their decisions need to be expressed in your model as well.

If HR is being taken out of the picture (which I doubt, but maybe) then there's no need to do this; the app can keep track of requests and the leave balance and say immediately whether the request is valid or not.  But I suspect it can't be this simple. :)

Comment: "Time Off Requests" themselves are a different 'model', and *they* are approved/disapproved. This is simply a "Time Ledger" for keeping track of actual debits/credits, which would occur after a request was approved. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
How have getting balance Debit-Credit for  running balamace ACCESS DATABASE
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Calendar" %>
<%
//java Code
String date = (new java.util.Date()).toString();
String UserName = request.getParameter("UserName");
String CusId= request.getParameter("CusId");
String AccountNo = request.getParameter("AccountNo");
String Debit = request.getParameter("Debit");
String Credit=request.getParameter("Credit");
String Balance=request.getParameter("Balance");
String sDate=request.getParameter("sDate");
try
{
String s="jdbc:odbc:Database1";
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(s);
Statement smt=conn.createStatement();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());
String sql= "SELECT  sDate, (SUM(Debit)*-1) + SUM(Credit)Balance FROM abcbank GROUP BY  sDate";
ResultSet result = smt.executeQuery(sql);
int count = 0;
while (result.next())
{
result.getString(1,"Debit");
result.getString(2,"Credit");
result.getString(3,"Balance");
result.getDate(4,startDate);

}

String update= "UPDATE abcbank SET Balance =Debit + Balance   WHERE AccountNo="+AccountNo+" ";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(update);
//statement.setString(1,"AccountNo");
int rowsUpdated = statement.executeUpdate();
if (rowsUpdated ==0)
{
out.println("This Emp does not Exists!");
}
else if(rowsUpdated ==1)
{
out.println("An existing user was updated successfully!");
}
conn.close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
  }

%>
</body>
</html>
```